# Why is my email client not rendering html email correctly?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I've read through a tonne of different similar questions and answers, and I understand that there are mass compatability issues with email clients. I also built my email using the mailchimp compatability guide, using table isntead of div etc...

On codepen it looks like this (minor differences as not completely up to date) -

https://codepen.io/Wrecket/pen/MWJzNrR

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <title></title>
    <style>



body {
    background-color: white;
font-family: Nunito, Montserrat, monaco,Consolas,Lucida Console,monospace;
}

.col-8{
  width:700px;
}

      
table{width:100%; border-spacing: 0px;}

.content{
   background-color: white;
   padding:0px 85px 75px 85px;
   font-size: 16px;
}

.line{
  border-top:1px solid #ddd;
}
      
.socialImage{
  padding-top: 3rem;
}


</style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: black; padding: 3rem 10rem;">
  <table class="content" style="text-align: center; border-radius: 18px 18px; padding-top: 2rem;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle" style="font-size: 3rem; color: rgb(127, 240, 58);"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <h1>Booking Confirmed</h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>booking for <span style="font-weight: bold">User Name </span> has been confirmed </p>                  
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 5rem 5rem;background-color:#f2f2f2;border-radius: 8px;">
        <table>
          <tr style="text-align: left">
            <td colspan="2">
              <p style="font-weight:bold">Signup Name</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              <p style="font-weight:bold">Total</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <table>
    <td style="height: 5rem; background-color:black; width: 100%;"></td>
  </table>
  
  <table class="content" style="border-radius: 18px 18px;">
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right;">
      <a style="        text-decoration: none;        display: inline-block;" href="@Model.IOSAppLink">
                                <img class="socialImage" width="161" height="50" border="0" alt="" src="https://playwaze.blob.core.windows.net/emailassets/AppStore.png" style="        display: block;">
                            </a>
    </td>
      <td style="text-align: left;">
        <a style="        text-decoration: none;        display: inline-block;" href="@Model.AndroidAppLink">
                                <img class="socialImage" width="169" height="50" border="0" alt="" src="https://playwaze.blob.core.windows.net/emailassets/googlePlay.png" style="        display: block;">
                            </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="width: 100%; text-align:center;">
        <p>
          Please do not reply directly to this email. If you have any questions or comments regarding this email, please contact us at support@plawaze.com
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
        <img style="height: 4rem;" src="https://f.hubspotusercontent00.net/hub/8806450/hubfs/Playwaze_Logo_Orange_%23EA8A41.png?height=120&name=Playwaze_Logo_Orange_%23EA8A41.png"> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="height: 1rem; width: 100%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <td colspan="2">
        Copyright &copy2021 Playwaze
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <td colspan="2">
        Contact us:
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <td colspan="2">
        The Lansbury Estate, 102 Lower Guilford Road, Woking, Surrey, GU21 2EP UK
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    <!--<div class="booking-container-summary">
        <div class="booking-summary">
            <div class="booking-summary-name ">
                @Model.ActivityName
            </div>
            <div class=" booking-summary-price">
                @Model.Price
            </div>
            <div class="booking-date booking-summary-date">
                @Model.GroupPlayDate
            </div>
            <div class="booking-address booking-summary-address">
                @Model.Location
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


    <br><br>
    <div style="width:100%;" class="booking-container-mobile-bottom">
        <div class="total-price-grid booking-price">

            <div>
                @Model.TotalPrice
            </div>
        </div>
<td class="content footer" style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:0px;">
              
                <table>

                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" style="        width: 50%;        padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;        font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;        direction: ltr;">
                            <a style="        text-decoration: none;        display: inline-block;" href="@Model.IOSAppLink">
                                <img class="socialImage" width="161" height="50" border="0" alt="" src="https://playwaze.blob.core.windows.net/emailassets/AppStore.png" style="        display: block;">
                            </a>

                        </td>
                        <td align="left" valign="top" style="        width: 50%;        padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;        font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;        direction: ltr;  ">
                            <a style="        text-decoration: none;        display: inline-block;" href="@Model.AndroidAppLink">
                                <img class="socialImage" width="169" height="50" border="0" alt="" src="https://playwaze.blob.core.windows.net/emailassets/googlePlay.png" style="        display: block;">
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td></td>
<p class="sans outro">
                    Please do not reply directly to this email. @Model.Text
                </p>
<td class="contactsection">
                <span class="footerlogo"></span>
                <p class="sans contact" style="margin:0px">
                    Copyright @  2019 Playwaze
                    <br>
                    Contact Us:
                    <br>
                    First Floor, Steward House, 14 Commercial Way, Woking, GU21 6ET
                </p>
            </td>
    </div>-->
</body>

</html>
```

but then on email it looks like this -

[image: Email page]

I fully get that its a compatability issue somewhere, but can anyone help me identifiying where? This is my first (and hopefully last) venture into creating an html email.

Comment: "but then on email" — Which email client are you using?

Comment: Agreed, more context on which email client would be helpful.

Comment: @Quentin, email client is not relevant here: an email should ideally be readable on any client. FYI it gives the same result as shown here using Thunderbird for instance

Comment: @julien.giband — Emails clients are relevant because Stackoverflow questions need to be *focused*. "How do I solve this specific layout problem in this email client?" is a good question while "How do I solve this collection of layout problems across all email clients?" is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you redact email as HTML, you have to think in older versions of HTML, such as HTML 4 and below. Plus email clients have some limitations as to what related resources they will download for obvious security reasons.

By just removing the HTML5 `DOCTYPE` declaration, linked fonts and linked style-sheets, and cleaning up inline declarations, I get to the following code:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: white;
            font-family: Nunito, Montserrat, monaco, Consolas, Lucida Console, monospace;
        }

        .col-8 {
            width: 700px;
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-spacing: 0px;
        }

        .content {
            background-color: white;
            padding: 0px 85px 75px 85px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .line {
            border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

        .socialImage {
            padding-top: 3rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: black; padding: 3rem 10rem;">
    <table class="content" style="text-align: center; border-radius: 18px 18px; padding-top: 2rem;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle" style="font-size: 3rem; color: rgb(127, 240, 58);"></i>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <h1>Booking Confirmed</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>booking for <span style="font-weight: bold">User Name </span>
                    has been confirmed </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 5rem 5rem;background-color:#f2f2f2; border-radius: 8px;">
                <table>
                    <tr style="text-align: left">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <p style="font-weight:bold">Signup Name</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <p style="font-weight:bold">Total</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
        <td style="height: 5rem; background-color:black; width: 100%;"></td>
    </table>

    <table class="content" style="border-radius: 18px 18px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">
                <a style="text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;" href="@Model.IOSAppLink">
                    <img class="socialImage" width="161" height="50" border="0" alt=""
                        src="https://playwaze.blob.core.windows.net/emailassets/AppStore.png" style="display: block;">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
                <a style="text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;" href="@Model.AndroidAppLink">
                    <img class="socialImage" width="169" height="50" border="0" alt=""
                        src="https://playwaze.blob.core.windows.net/emailassets/googlePlay.png" style="display: block;">
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="width: 100%; text-align:center;">
                <p>
                    Please do not reply directly to this email. If you have any questions or
                    comments regarding this email, please contact us at support@plawaze.com
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                <img style="height: 4rem;"
                    src="https://f.hubspotusercontent00.net/hub/8806450/hubfs/Playwaze_Logo_Orange_%23EA8A41.png?height=120&name=Playwaze_Logo_Orange_%23EA8A41.png">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="height: 1rem; width: 100%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align: center;">
            <td colspan="2">
                Copyright &copy2021 Playwaze
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align: center;">
            <td colspan="2">
                Contact us:
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align: center;">
            <td colspan="2">
                The Lansbury Estate, 102 Lower Guilford Road, Woking, Surrey, GU21 2EP UK
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Which gives a result with no icons or fancy fonts, but a presentation much closer to what you're looking for. You might be able to further approach your aim by using standard fonts (Helevetica Arial ?), and embedded images for icons

Now you also need to write cleaner code if you want to be able to debug it:

- Stick to either CSS in a `<style>` element (preferably) or inline declarations; *not* both
- Indent correctly
- Avoid unnecessary spaces scattered in your code
- And so on

Finally, using older HTML tags does not necessarily mean having tables all over the place. You could use a table for layout as it will help you to center and space your document parts, but then have common blocks inside each cell. Code will be cleaner, and therefore easier to read for humans as well as email clients...

***Edit***
One more point: depending on how your email body will be encoded, you might experience issues with CSS lines starting with a '.'. Only fix I've found for this is to avoid starting lines with dots, for example rewrite all CSS lines like

```
.col-8 {
```

into

```
*.col-8 {
```

or wrap your whole email body inside a `<div>` with an `id`, and prefix every css rule with this id, which will also help in webmail clients to separate your CSS from the site's

Comment: Thanks for this - im pretty much there now. Ive removed all <style> items and added them as inline, and done as stated above.

The only issue i'm now facing is that outlook seems to break any css rules on image size and renders the image at its full size regardless of what I try. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I don't know about this problem specific to Outlook. maybe you could try and use the old `width` and `height` HTML attributes on you `<img>`, or render it as background using CSS

Comment: @julien.giband seems you have resolved your issue it seems but just wanted to point out, you have duplicate classes on tables. Also the screenshot posted is of dark mode Outlook?

Comment: @MattFuller I think Syfer's comment was to you

Comment: Hi @Syfer, Yeah - removed all classes and replaced with inline CSS, and yeah I know dark mode was on - but thank you for making sure!